# Azure Synapse Spark Pool - How to install the whl file that is uploaded in storage?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I have uploaded my .whl file to the storage location (ADLS gen2) that is associated with Azure Synapse Analytics at the below location -

```
/mySynapseLinkedStorage/synapse/workspaces/myWorkSpace/sparkpools/mySparkPool/libraries/python/my_etl-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

How can I attach it to my Spark pool and use it in the notebook?

I have tried the below 2 methods already and they are too slow -

*Method 1* -

From the Azure Portal - manually add the .whl file to the *workspace packages* and then to the *spark pool packages*. This method is too slow and takes **approx. 30 mins** to complete.

*Method 2* -
From the *Azure CLI* (in Powershell) - by running the below commands -

2.1 Upload the .whl file to the workspace

```
az synapse workspace-package upload --workspace-name myWorkSpace --package "C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\TestGitHub\dist\my_etl-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl"
```

2.2 Attach the package to the spark pool

```
az synapse spark pool update --name mySparkPoolName--workspace-name myWorkSpace --resource-group myRG --package-action Add --package my_etl-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

This method is also slow and takes **approx. 20 mins** to complete.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Sanket Kelkar

Comment: Update - I was able to get it working using the Spark Pool built on Apache Spark 2.4 (Uploading the .whl file to the storage and directly importing it in the code).
But it fails for Apache Spark 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3. Does anyone know if MS supports the .whl file installation in this fashion for Apache Spark 3.x?

Comment: according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-workspace-packages) > This method of managing custom wheel files will not be supported on the Azure Synapse Runtime for Apache Spark 3.0. We need to refer to the Workspace packages feature to manage custom wheel files.