# Error while connecting to SQL server using pyodbc from Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: sql-server, azure, ubuntu, pyodbc, azure-synapse

I am facing the below error when trying to connect to Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool from Azure Synapse Spark notebook using `pyodbc`

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Below is the simple code that I am using -

```
import pyodbc
server = 'myServer'
database = 'myDB'
username = 'myUser'
password = 'myPassword'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

I think the Synapse Workspace does not come with a pre-installed ODBC driver for SQL Server as compared to the Azure Functions. The same code runs successfully from Azure Functions.

I have gone through this link - https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark/
and tried running the below code from my notebook cell -

```
%%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc
```

But it gives me the below error -

```
E: This command can only be used by root.
sh: 2: cannot create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list: Permission denied
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this or install the ODBC driver from the Synapse notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the error in my environment and got similar error.**

[image]

The cause of error is the driver you are using for connection is not present in your synapse notebook.

**To check the driver installed in your synapse notebook  use the following commands.**

```py
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()
```

[image]

**Then use that driver to connect with SQL:**

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! 
@pratik can you please look into this and share your thoughts?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194151/how-to-use-the-whl-file-in-the-spark-pool-in-azure?comment=question#newest-question-comment

Comment: Please post it as new question on this platform so other community members can also help you on that.

Comment: Sure, here it is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75887597/azure-synapse-spark-pool-how-to-install-the-whl-file-that-is-uploaded-in-stora